# Creating Dynamic Title for Matlab scatter plot

Tags: matlab

As the title would such suggest I would like to create title for my scatter plots that I create inside of the loop using the index number, here is my code:

```
for i = 1: 12
figure
scatter(PlotY(:,i),PlotY(:,i+1));
hold on
scatter(PlotN(:,i),PlotN(:,i+1),'d');

title(strcat('Feature ',i,'VS Feature ',i+1));
end
```

The plots work more than fine, just I would like to have title displayed as "Feature 1 vs Feature 2" when i = 1. But I'm currently getting:

[image]

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make the numbers into strings as well:

```
for i = 1: 12
    figure
    scatter(PlotY(:,i),PlotY(:,i+1));
    hold on
    scatter(PlotN(:,i),PlotN(:,i+1),'d');

    title(['Feature ' num2str(i) ' VS Feature ' num2str(i+1)]);
end
```